# On keyup event, when shift + key released , shift before key , event.key not reflects key

Tags: javascript, shift, onkeyup

In javascript ,onkeyup event, when I press shfit + key , then release the shift **before** the key, I don't get the event.key for the key , instead I get "shift".
Is there a way to get the event.key for the key ?

Comment: The behaviour you describe is logically what you should get. However you probably want to check whether a combination is inputted?

Comment: Am I getting your question correctly? You want to register a keyup event for a key that... did not keyupped? What is that you're actually trying to solve? Seems like an XY-Problem

Comment: Thank you all for the rapid answers and responses. 
I expected to get the Key of the combination , as it is in case of keydown event.
The root of the problem was the Devops debugger which showed only the last upped key which was the 'Shift'.
To @Alexander Nenashev , thank you for the nice example to extract the key. It deepened me into the matters and helped me in the way.  In final , I indeed used a combination of keyup and keydown events.
It took me a lot of time , this why I belated in my response.

Comment: @YaakovWhise, what is missing in my solution then?

Comment: In first glance at the Run Code Snippet of @Alexander Nenashev I saw that the Key was extracted without Shift , and this caught my mind. It helped me to assume that the event.key indeed gets me the Key besides the Shift. As I mantioned, it was lack in my perception of the matter plus some difficulties in Devops.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remember pressed keys in a set (this prevents registering repeating keydowns):

```js
const pressedKeys = new Set;

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => pressedKeys.add(e.key));
document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  pressedKeys.delete(e.key);
  e.key === 'Shift' && pressedKeys.size && console.log('Still pressed:', ...pressedKeys);
  pressedKeys.clear();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Key up triggers the moment a key is released. It's impossible to release two keys at the same time but it is possible to press them at the same time:

```js
var keysPressed = []

window.document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (keysPressed.indexOf(event.key) < 0) {
    keysPressed.push(event.key)
  }
});

window.document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  if (keysPressed.length) {
    // Show which keys where pressed
    console.log(keysPressed)
  }

  // Empty array 
  keysPressed = []
});
```